# How to execute this ffmpeg command for multiple videos in a folder and rename them on Linux terminal

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, terminal, command-line

I'm trying to change the framerate of my video to 15fps and I need to do that for 100+ videos that are in the same folder

For processing a single video I use the following command-
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v fps=fps=15 processed/input_15fpst.mp4`

How do I do this for multiple videos in the folder and add a suffix _15fps to them ? I'm not very familiar with Linux programming

Thank you so much!

I tried doing this-
`for f in *.MP4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter:v fps=fps=15 process/"$f"; done`

But I want to rename the file as well, how do I change my loop?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "specify the format of the output". Do you not want the format to be MP4? Does it depend on the input file? What exactly is wrong with the `for` loop you already came up with?

Comment: I'm not sure but I wrote it again and it worked 
for f in *.MP4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter:v fps=fps=15 process/"$f"; done
I'm figuring out how I can rename the file now. If my earlier file is called "input", how can I call the output "input_15fps". I've edited my question above

Comment: `... -vf fps=15 "process/${f%.*}_15fps.${f##*.}"`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for f in *.MP4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter:v fps=fps=15 process/"${f}_15fps"; done
```